# Delete message using AE.Net.Mail

Tags: c#

I'm trying to delete some specific emails. I'm using AE.Net.Mail. I tried a few thinks but nothing worked yet. I've read about expunge, somethink that could work. So far it hasn't and i have the feeling it doesn't work with AE.Net.Mail.

So can you guys help me out?
I filter the messages like this:

```
var Mail = imap.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Subject("Generated Report"));!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
List<Lazy<MailMessage>> Mail = imap.SearchMessages(
    SearchCondition.Subject("Generated Report")).ToList();
imap.DeleteMessage(Mail.First().Value);
imap.Expunge();
```